# Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\libsys\edit.php on line 3

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is a newbie question but this error keeps bugging me for a while now please help ty

```
<?PHP
include "configdb.php";
$id = $_POST['id'];

if (isset($id))
{
    $newName = $id;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM booklist WHERE id = $id';
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die("Could not update".mysql_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
    $id = $row[0];
    $title = $row[1];
    $author = $row[2];
    $ISBN = $row[3];
    $category = $row[4];
    $image_upload = $row[5];
    $image_upload2 = $row[6];

}
?>
```

Comment: Your `$_POST` array does not have element with index `id`. Normally you should check at first `if (isset($_POST['id'])) $id = intval($_POST['id']); else $id = false;` and later `if ($id) ..` And read about SQL injections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear but I believe you should move the `$id = $_POST['id']` inside your `if` statement

and the code should be:

```
<?PHP
include "configdb.php";


if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `booklist` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die("Could not update".mysql_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
    $id = $row[0];
    $title = $row[1];
    $author = $row[2];
    $ISBN = $row[3];
    $category = $row[4];
    $image_upload = $row[5];
    $image_upload2 = $row[6];
}
?>
```

---

**EXTRA INFO**

If what I believe this question is about getting a book id from a book list, then run a query in db to return the results then a better code will be something like this:

```
<?PHP
include "configdb.php";


if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM booklist WHERE id = $id") or die("Could not update".mysql_error());
  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql); // get the number of returning rows (0 means no query match found, > 0 means a query match found)
  if($rows > 0)
  {
    while($i = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
      $book_id        = $sql[0];
      $book_title     = $sql[1];
      $author         = $sql[2];
      $ISBN           = $sql[3];
      $category       = $sql[4];
      $image_upload   = $sql[5];
      $image_upload2  = $sql[6];

      // the rest of your code and what you want to do with the result....
    }
  }
  eles // no results found message
  {
  echo 'Sorry, no results found.';
  } // end of else 
}
?>
```

Also please note that you can use the column name instead of `$sql[0], $sql[1], $sql[3]`

so if your first table columns has a name of `book_id` then it can be

`$book_id = $sql['book_id'];` instead of `$book_id = $sql[0];`.  This much easier to deal with when you work in your code so you don't have to go back and fourth to your db to check indexes of columns.  also, it will help you a lot when you update your code or share it with others.

Comment: Why? If it was like that $id won't be assigned before the `if` statement.

Comment: @ZeeTee, in his code he defined `$newName = $id;` where it is not used anywhere in the query.  I believe he has a books list form and from that form he get an id of one of the books to use in his query  and get the results.

Comment: actually you are spot on SULTAN that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You should do something with `$id` to prevent SQL injection.  `mysqli_real_escape_string`, `intval`, something.

Comment: @PierceAldinAcierto Great I could help, please see my updated answer with extra information that might help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL Statement is not checking a numeric ID value from your form, instead it's checking the string `$id`. Need to change that:

```
'SELECT * FROM booklist WHERE id = '. $id
```

Comment: Not even "the string", since it isn't quoted.  It's just invalid SQL.  This isn't the cause of the error mentioned, but it's well worth noting.

Comment: How is it different from the one that TS has?

Comment: @Cheery: The question has a single-quoted string.  `$id` won't be interpolated.

Comment: I don't even know php. But I knew it couldn't be right.

Comment: @cHao sorry, did not look there, but still it does not prevent from SQL injection )

Comment: @Cheery: It sure doesn't.  You could say `...id = ' . intval($id)` to take care of that.